# Super complicated mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, select, join

The database (Mysql) witch i do query comes from an telephony system, and i need to read how many agents (event_parties.agent_id) is logged into different group (event_groups.group_id).

Each time an agent logges in to an group an new record is entered inside **events** table with **event_id=29**, if logout **event_id=30** at the same time an new entry in table **event_parties** appears with same **g_event_id** and the agent_id representing the agent,
 also in table **events_groups** an new entry appears with same **g_event_id** and group_id representing th egroup that the agents logges in/out to(inside the table event_groups the same g_event_id could the same for more than one entry if agent logges in/out more than one group at the same time).

So my thinking is that i could get the logged in agents in and group_id by selecting all records where there are no newer entry (event_time) with same event_groups.group_id and same event_parties.agent_id and the events.event_id is between 29 and 30.

events.event_id =29 means that agents logges in.
events.event_id =30 means that agents logges out.

I have some serious difficulties to design such an mysql select :(

Here are some example data in each table.

Table:
**events**

```
g_event_id   event_id   event_time
----------   --------   ----------
7816         31     2016-11-03 09:46:18
7815         30     2016-11-03 09:45:18
7814         31     2016-11-03 09:44:18
7813         29     2016-11-03 09:43:18 
7812         30     2016-11-03 09:42:18
7811         29     2016-11-03 09:41:18
7810         31     2016-11-03 09:40:18 
7809         29     2016-11-03 09:39:18
7808         31     2016-11-03 09:38:18
7807         7      2016-11-03 09:37:18
7806         29     2016-11-03 09:36:18
7805         30     2016-11-03 09:35:18
7804         30     2016-11-03 09:34:18
7803         29     2016-11-03 09:33:18
7802         29     2016-11-03 09:32:18
```

Table:
**event_parties**

```
g_event_id   agent_id
----------   --------
7816            1
7815            1
7814            1
7813            1
7812            1
7811            1
7810            2
7809            2
7808            2
7807            3
7806            3
7805            3
7804            3
7803            3
7802            3
```

Table:
**event_groups**

```
g_event_id   group_id
----------   --------
7816            1
7815            1
7814            1
7813            1
7813            2
7813            3
7813            4
7812            1
7811            1
7810            1
7809            1
7808            1
7807            1
7806            1
7806            3
7805            4
7804            1
7804            2
7803            4
7802            1
7802            2
```

From tables above i want my select statement result to be:

```
group_id    agent_id
--------    --------
4           1
3           1
2           1
1           2
1           3
3           3
```

Is such a query possible, is there any sql genius out there :)

/ Kristian

Comment: Ideally, if you could make a SQL Fiddle, you would do wonders to have a working set we can test against.

Comment: Ok, let me try out the SQL Fiddle, will fill that in, be back in some minutes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT group_id, agent_id
FROM (SELECT agent_id, eg.group_id, if(event_id = 29, 1, -1) AS transitions
      FROM event_parties      ep
           JOIN `events` e ON ep.g_event_id = e.g_event_id
           JOIN event_groups eg ON ep.g_event_id = eg.g_event_id
      WHERE e.event_id IN (29, 30)) AS t
GROUP BY agent_id, group_id
HAVING sum(transitions) > 0
ORDER BY agent_id, group_id DESC
```

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4315/14)

I think that this will do what you are saying.  For every agent/group combination, it sets number of transitions to 1 if they login and -1 if they log out.  Looking over the whole data set, if they have logged in and then logged out, the sum will be 0 for a specific agent group, which is calculated in the outer query.

This does depend on not starting with a log out event for a specific agent/group combination.  If the data set you are looking starts with a log out event, then the user will never appear to be logged out.

Alternatively, you could get the same result by looking at the last record, and determining if it's a 29 or a 30, and only displaying the ones that are 29.

```
SELECT group_id, agent_id
FROM (SELECT agent_id, group_id, max(e.g_event_id) AS last_event_id
      FROM event_parties      ep
           JOIN `events` e ON ep.g_event_id = e.g_event_id
           JOIN event_groups eg ON ep.g_event_id = eg.g_event_id
      WHERE e.event_id IN (29, 30)
      GROUP BY agent_id, group_id) AS last_event
     JOIN `events` e ON e.g_event_id = last_event.last_event_id
WHERE e.event_id = 29;
```

This is less dependent on where you are starting in the series, but the join is slightly more complex.

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4315/14)

---

FWIW syntax style change using `natural join`:

```
select group_id, agent_id 
  from ( select agent_id, group_id, 
                max( g_event_id ) as g_event_id 
           from event_parties natural join `events` natural join event_groups
          where event_id in (29, 30)
          group
             by agent_id, group_id ) as last_event
       natural join `events`
 where event_id = 29;
```

Comment: Really amazing!

Comment: You last query works perfect for me as the starting records isnt reliable :)

Answer (score 0):

I just make a Demo now clear me what you want

```
select g.group_id,p.agent_id from event_groups g 
join event_parties p on g.g_event_id=p.g_event_id
join events e on p.g_event_id =e.g_event_id where e.event_id=29
```